# Python - Selenium, how to grab all li elements under div class between two h3 tags

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

I'm new to using Selenium and I have trouble with scraping data between two h3 tags.
Here's a part of the HTML code that I'm trying to scrape, the web site is https://apps.apple.com/ie/app/rt%C3%A9-player/id484129073
[image]
[image]

```
App Functionality
Customer Support

Third-Party Advertising
Advertising Data

Analytics
Product Interaction
Advertising Data

App Functionality
User ID
Device ID
Crash Data
Performance Data
Other Diagnostic Data
```

Above is what I wanted to grab, but I got as below:

```
App Functionality
Customer Support
-----------------------
Third-Party Advertising
Advertising Data
Product Interaction
Advertising Data
User ID
Device ID
Crash Data
Performance Data
Other Diagnostic Data
-----------------------
Analytics
Product Interaction
Advertising Data
User ID
Device ID
Crash Data
Performance Data
Other Diagnostic Data
-----------------------
App Functionality
User ID
Device ID
Crash Data
Performance Data
Other Diagnostic Data
-----------------------
```

It seems the results contain all li elements after next h3 tags, and my code is:

```
h3_tags = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='privacy-type__purpose-heading']"))
        )
        
for i in range(len(h3_tags)):
  li_tags = h3_tags[i].find_elements(By.XPATH, "./following-sibling::div[@class='privacy-type__grid']/descendant::li")
  print(h3_tags[i].text)
  for li in li_tags:
    print(li.text)
  print('-----------------------')
```

Is there any way to only keep the li-element between two h3 tags?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you provided the correct URL? The XPATHs doesn't even identifies any element, strange :/

Comment: @undetectedSelenium Yes I checked again, it works for me. Maybe because the url is only valid in my region? Not sure about that....

Comment: I'm seeing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri5V5.png)

Comment: @undetectedSelenium Oh you need to click the ‘See Details‘ next to App Privacy

Comment: Even after clicking on ‘See Details‘ next to App Privacy, on the `App Privacy` popup I don't find your expected sequence. Is there a pattern in your requirement?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I add another pic in the question, does that help

Comment: You want `App Functionality` and `Customer Support` both? Or only `Customer Support` within `App Functionality`, and same for other headings?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I want to grab the heading 'App Functionality' and li-element 'Customer Support' both, and same for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems the results contain all li elements after next h3 tags

This happens because `following-sibling` selects all the siblings following a given node. For example if `h3_tags[i]` is "Third-Party Advertising", then the xpath

```
./following-sibling::div[@class='privacy-type__grid']
```

selects all the four `div` elements following `h3`, instead of only the first one.

[image]

What you want are the `div` elements that are immediately adjacent siblings of a given `h3`. You can do this with the following xpath

```
h3_tags = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='privacy-type__purpose-heading']")
xpath = "./following-sibling::div[last() = count(preceding-sibling::h3[1]/following-sibling::div)]/descendant::li"
for h3 in h3_tags:
    print(h3.text.upper())
    print('\n'.join( [li.text for li in h3.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath)] ))
    print()
```

Output

```
APP FUNCTIONALITY
Customer Support

THIRD-PARTY ADVERTISING
Advertising Data

ANALYTICS
Product Interaction
Advertising Data

APP FUNCTIONALITY
User ID
Device ID
Crash Data
Performance Data
Other Diagnostic Data
```

To understand what that xpath means, we can isolate two parts:

- `./following-sibling::div[last()]`

selects the last `div` which comes after the `h3` element (current node). Notice that `last()` is simply a number, corresponding to the position of the last element, so if there are four `div` then `last()=4` and we obtain `div[4]` which is in fact the fourth `div`.

- `div[last() = count(preceding-sibling::h3[1]/following-sibling::div)]`

compares the position of the last `div` with the count of preceding sibling `div` elements that come after the first `h3` sibling of the selected `div`. If the position of the last `div` is the same as the count of preceding `div` elements, it means that the selected `div` is the only `div` following the `h3` element.